# python command substitution for linux commands

Tags: python

I am trying to use command substitution for building a linux command from a python script, but am not able to get the following simple example to work:

```
LS="/bin/ls -l"
FILENAME="inventory.txt"

cmd = "_LS _FILENAME "
ps= subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
print output
```

Thanks!

JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string substitution](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
cmd = '{} {}'.format(LS, FILENAME)
```

or (in Python2.6):

```
cmd = '{0} {1}'.format(LS, FILENAME)
```

---

```
import subprocess
import shlex

LS="/bin/ls -l"
FILENAME="inventory.txt"

cmd = '{} {}'.format(LS, FILENAME)    
ps = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),
                      stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
output, err = ps.communicate()
print(output)
```

---

Or, using the [sh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh):

```
import sh
FILENAME = 'inventory.txt'
print(sh.ls('-l', FILENAME, _err_to_out=True))
```

Comment: This worked very nicely.  For some reason I thought command substitution for python would be under the same title and not Formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Be wary of security when doing it like this. It's way too easy to add shell injection due to improper quoting.